# Цінува́льник, оці́нник, поцінувач, ціни́тель

Tags: синоніми

В Російсько-українському народному сучасному словнику 2009– наводиться такий синонімічний ряд до слова цінитель:

> Ценитель – (вещей) ціновни́к, цінува́льник, оці́нник, цінува́ч, поцінувач, (талантов) цінува́льник, поціно́вувач, цінува́ч, ціни́тель.
>   [Марі зважилась покохати серцеїда зі «слабким звуком», про мистецьку вартість і забезпечену кар’єру якого вона наслухалася стільки теплих слів від дуже надійного поцінувача (Є.Попович, перекл. Т.Мана)].
>   Однак вже у наведеному прикладі є невідповідність вживання слова "поцінувач" стосовно мистецтва.
>   [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) слово *цінувальник* (яке повинно стосуватися до речей і нематеріальних явищ) відносить до ряду 
>   ШАНУВА́ЛЬНИК (той, хто виявляє шану до когось, чогось, схиляється перед ким-, чим-небудь), ЦІНУВА́ЛЬНИК, ЦІНИ́ТЕЛЬрідше,ЗВЕЛИ́ЧНИК, ЛЮБИ́ТЕЛЬтільки чого,ПОКЛО́ННИКзаст.

Чи буде помилкою вживання, скажімо, вислову "ціновник комфорту", "поціновувач складних крутиголовок"?